# SVG changes the size of its container (expands it). How to prevent it?

Tags: html, css, svg

I put SVG picture in some block and the block has expanded

I've tried to change svg attributes but then I get different looks of the image - outline path gets thicker

Html code

```
<section class="image item item2 cat_image">   

        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 640 800" width="640pt" height="800pt"><defs> 
           <path...></g>
         </svg>
    </section>
```

CSScode

```
svg {

  transform: scale(0.45);
  transform-origin: bottom;

}
```

I want the width of the block be the same as svg picture.

UPDATE:
Also if I set width to the block to make it compact then the image shrinks as well

Comment: Make the parent block `display:inline-block`?

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: Then you need to show the problem in a snippet. I'd also remove the height and width from your SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Paulie_D's suggestion of using `display: inline-block` should be the correct solution.

That's what I've used in the following example, and it works okay.

```css
section {
  display: inline-block;
  background: linen;
}


.smaller {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 640 800" width="640pt" height="800pt">
    <ellipse cx="320" cy="400" rx="320" ry="400" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
  </svg>

</section>


<p/>


<section class="smaller">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="isolation:isolate" viewBox="0 0 640 800" width="640pt" height="800pt">
    <ellipse cx="320" cy="400" rx="320" ry="400" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
  </svg>

</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
   div.outer{
    background:red;
    width:200px;
   }
</style>

<div class="outer">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100pt">
       <path d="M50,40   l100,0  0,50  -100,0  0,-50"
       style="stroke: #000000; fill:green;" />    
   </svg>
</div>
```